# PIXI.js getting another entity into the game class from a separate file

Tags: typescript, pixi.js

Could I get some help please. I'm using Pixi.js and trying to get my player class to a separate .ts file so I can import that into my main game class. Note sure if this is the best way to do things, but so far so good. I just can't get the game to render the sprite. Any help would be great or even some examples, been googling for a while now. I must be stuffing something up somewhere in how I'm getting the import or something, but still very new to TS in some regards. Oh I'm also using Parcel for my bundler.

**app.ts**

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import Player from './Player';


class Game extends PIXI.Application {
    private player:Player;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.view.width = 1000;
        this.view.height = 600;
        document.getElementById('game').appendChild(this.view);

        this.setupPlayer();
        PIXI.Ticker.shared.add(this.gameLoop)
    }

    setupPlayer() {
        console.log('setting up player');
        this.player = new Player(this.stage, 300, 300);
    }

    gameLoop(delta) {
        this.player.x += .1;
    }
}

window.onload = function () {
    const game = new Game()
}
```

**Player.ts**

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';

export default class Player extends PIXI.Sprite {

    private player:PIXI.Sprite;

    constructor(stage, x:number, y:number) {
        super();

        this.player = PIXI.Sprite.from("/images/player.png");
        this.player.anchor.set(.5);
        this.player.position.x = x;
        this.player.position.y = y;
        stage.addChild(this.player);

    }
}
```

Comment: OK I've made some progress and can get my player to show now. But I can seem to access it from inside the game loop of PIXI's Shared ticker. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK I've made some progress and can get my player to show now. But I can't seem to access it from inside the game loop of PIXI's Shared ticker. Any ideas?

**app.ts**

```
import * as PIXI from 'pixi.js';
import { PixiPlugin } from "gsap/PixiPlugin";
import Player from './Player';

PixiPlugin.registerPIXI(PIXI);

class Game extends PIXI.Application {
    player:Player;
    ticker:PIXI.Ticker;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.view.width = 1000;
        this.view.height = 600;
        document.getElementById('game').appendChild(this.view);

        this.setupPlayer();
        this.ticker = PIXI.Ticker.shared.add(this.gameLoop);
    }

    setupPlayer():void {
        this.player = new Player(this.stage);
        this.player.setPosition(200,200);
    }

    gameLoop(delta):void {
        //neither of these work as player is undefined here, why is that?
        // this.player.x += 1;
        // this.player.position.x +=1;
    }
}

const game = new Game()
```

**player.ts**

```
import {Sprite, Texture} from 'pixi.js';

export default class Player extends Sprite {

    constructor(stage) {
        super(Texture.from(require("../../images/player.png")));

        this.anchor.set(.5)
        this.scale.set(.5)
        stage.addChild(this);
    }

    setPosition(x:number, y:number):void {
        this.position.x = x;
        this.position.y = y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh my goodness, I'm an idiot. I hate asking a question and then after going for a walk and coming back trying 1 thing and it works... The Ticker was missing a context which in this case is just a reference to the class that it is in. This was the fix.

Instead of

```
this.ticker = PIXI.Ticker.shared.add(this.gameLoop);
```

**use**

```
PIXI.Ticker.shared.add(this.gameLoop, this);
```